# How do I construct a self-referential/recursive SQLModel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, adjacency-list, self-referencing-table, sqlmodel

I want to define a model that has a **self-referential** (or **recursive**) foreign key using [`SQLModel`](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/). (This relationship pattern is also sometimes referred to as an **adjacency list**.) The pure `SQLAlchemy` implementation is described [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/self_referential.html) in their documentation.

Let's say I want to implement the basic **tree structure** as described in the `SQLAlchemy` example linked above, where I have a `Node` model and each instance has an `id` primary key, a `data` field (say of type `str`), and an optional reference (read *foreign key*) to another node that we call its **parent** node (field name `parent_id`).

Ideally, every `Node` object should have a `parent` attribute, which will be `None`, if the node has no parent node; otherwise it will contain (a pointer to) the parent `Node` object.

And even better, every `Node` object should have a `children` attribute, which will be a list of `Node` objects that reference it as their parent.

The question is twofold:

1. What is an elegant way to implement this with `SQLModel`?
2. How would I create such node instances and insert them into the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`sqlmodel.Relationship`](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/relationship-attributes/define-relationships-attributes/#what-are-these-relationship-attributes) function allows explicitly passing additional keyword-arguments to the `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship` constructor that is being called under the hood via the `sa_relationship_kwargs` parameter. This parameter expects a mapping of strings representing the `SQLAlchemy` parameter names to the values we want to pass through as arguments.

Since `SQLAlchemy` relationships provide the [`remote_side`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.remote_side) parameter for just such an occasion, we can leverage that directly to construct the self-referential pattern with minimal code. The documentation mentions this in passing, but crucially the `remote_side` value

> may be passed as a Python-evaluable string when using Declarative.

This is exactly what we need. The only missing piece then is the proper use of the [`back_populates`](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/relationship-attributes/back-populates/) parameter and we can build the model like so:

```py
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, Session, SQLModel, create_engine


class Node(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'node'  # just to be explicit

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    data: str
    parent_id: Optional[int] = Field(
        foreign_key='node.id',  # notice the lowercase "n" to refer to the database table name
        default=None,
        nullable=True
    )
    parent: Optional['Node'] = Relationship(
        back_populates='children',
        sa_relationship_kwargs=dict(
            remote_side='Node.id'  # notice the uppercase "N" to refer to this table class
        )
    )
    children: list['Node'] = Relationship(back_populates='parent')

# more code below...
```

**Side note:** We define `id` as optional as is customary with `SQLModel` to avoid being nagged by our IDE when we want to create an instance, for which the `id` will only be known, after we have added it to the database. The `parent_id` and `parent` attributes are obviously defined as optional because not every node needs to have a parent in our model.

To test that everything works the way we expect it to:

```py
def test() -> None:
    # Initialize database & session:
    sqlite_file_name = 'database.db'
    sqlite_uri = f'sqlite:///{sqlite_file_name}'
    engine = create_engine(sqlite_uri, echo=True)
    SQLModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(engine)

    # Initialize nodes:
    root_node = Node(data='I am root')

    # Set the children's `parent` attributes;
    # the parent nodes' `children` lists are then set automatically:
    node_a = Node(parent=root_node, data='a')
    node_b = Node(parent=root_node, data='b')
    node_aa = Node(parent=node_a, data='aa')
    node_ab = Node(parent=node_a, data='ab')

    # Add to the parent node's `children` list;
    # the child node's `parent` attribute is then set automatically:
    node_ba = Node(data='ba')
    node_b.children.append(node_ba)

    # Commit to DB:
    session.add(root_node)
    session.commit()

    # Do some checks:
    assert root_node.children == [node_a, node_b]
    assert node_aa.parent.parent.children[1].parent is root_node
    assert node_ba.parent.data == 'b'
    assert all(n.data.startswith('a') for n in node_ab.parent.children)
    assert (node_ba.parent.parent.id == node_ba.parent.parent_id == root_node.id) \
           and isinstance(root_node.id, int)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

All the assertions are satisfied and the test runs without a hitch.

Also, by using the `echo=True` switch for the database engine, we can verify in our log output that the table is created as we expected:

```sql
CREATE TABLE node (
    id INTEGER, 
    data VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    parent_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES node (id)
)
```